How can I resize the image in React Native? (a simple question)
Here is my Card component's code:
const AnnouncementsCard = ({title, content, imageSrc}) => {
  return (
    <View className="bg-white items-center resize-x justify-center rounded-lg p-2 m-2">
      <Image className="flex-1 flex h-48 w-48 m-2 items-center justify-center" source={{uri: imageSrc}}/>
      <Text className="flex flex-1 text-l font-bold m-2">{title}</Text>
      <Text className="flex flex-1 text-l align-end items-end justify-end font-light m-2">{content}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

I want the image to cover the screen. How can I do it using Nativewind?

One way is to use ImageBackground, something like this:
<ImageBackground
  source={{ uri: imageSrc }}
  resizeMode="cover"
  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Text ...>{title}</Text>
  ...
</ImageBackground>


I want it to make with className, like
<Image className="flex-1 flex h-96 w-96 m-2 items-center justify-center" source={{uri: imageSrc}}/>

